# Should we use preset-react if we are using preset-typescript with jsx option set to 'react'?

Tags: typescript, babeljs

I use babel and `preset-typescript` to transpile react tsx file. As the doc says, when `jsx` option is set to `react`, `preset-typescript` will transpile `<div />` to `React.createElement("div")` and output js file. So if it is that, do we still need `preset-react` which i think will do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `jsx` option, do you mean `jsxPragma` in this preset or `jsx` in `tsconfig.json` file?

And then, can `@babel/preset-typescript` do that now? I just used babel to transfer only one file named `index.tsx` containing structures such as `<div>...</div>`. Of course, I set almost possible options which you mean, however, there is nothing happening to `<div>...</div>` until I use `@babel/preset-react`.

In my opinion, the option you mean is aimed to let babel know the import of react is not a type import, and not to remove JSX expression as [preset-typescript doc](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-typescript#docsNav) says

The following is babel config I used first.

```json
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/env",
    [
      "@babel/preset-typescript",
      {
        "isTSX": true,
        "allExtensions": true,
        "jsxPragma": "React",
        "jsxPragmaFrag": "React.Fragment"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: I mean `jsx` in `tsconfig.json`. It seems to have nothing to do with `@babel/preset-typescript`??

Comment: At least it does not work on mine, have you try this by yourself?